# Integration services feature is not found in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to install the following features in SQL Server 2008 R2:

- BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio)
- Integration Services

But setup is not showing me this feature in the installation window.

I downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition from this link :

[sql server 2008 r2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30438)

but I cant find Integration services feature in this setup.

help me with suggestion to install Integration services . Also provide with links to download sql server 2008 r2 enterprise edition

Comment: You need to make sure to download the **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services** edition - the **Advanced Services** version does include the BIDS

Comment: @marc_s ,  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services edition does not support integration services . what can i do for that.

Comment: Buy a full version of SQL Server .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express **does not** supports Integration Services.

Business Intelligence Development Studio is not included into Express edition, but it is inculded into [Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842) edition.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for comparison table of features supported by different editions of SQL Server.

You have to install at least Standard edition in order to be able to use Integration Services, but note - is is **not** free to use like Express edition.

Comment: is there any trial version available for standard edition or enterprise edition

Comment: @dheena, Well, for example Microsoft offers to download  180-days trial of SQL Server Standard Edition as Hyper-V image [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26113). I haven't seen any other trial options.

Comment: In the link there were 6 parts ( 1 .exe file and 5 rar files ) . Tell me wheather i must download all 6 parts or not